# How to open A-Frame inspector programmatically when the page loads

Tags: aframe

I need to open the inspector automatically when the page loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke the `openInspector` function manually after a-scene loads:

```
var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
  sceneEl.addEventListener('loaded', function () {
    sceneEl.components.inspector.openInspector();
 });
```

Working example:

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/brawny-candle-shrine?path=index.html%3A17%3A50